# How to display the previous result if user click refresh the page in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working Image gallery website. Image search page will work like google image search. On scroll it shows next results using jquery. How to display the same result if user refresh the page?

Thanks, Sham

Comment: The question is not clear, what you supposed to do? Showing the result from the beginning or from where the user has refreshed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use query string to get the user search parameters or you can use the search text field to show the result on refresh of page.

Answer (score 0):

Using query parameter will help only to show the page from the beginning after refresh, But what i would do is,

There are two options,

1. Using [cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)
2. Using HTML5 [local Storage or session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage)

I prefer the second one, 
But in both way you can cache the current search data, therefore can be used later. This will help you to display different page of results, where the query parameter remains same.